# Substituting Values from another python file to a current one

Tags: python

I'm using an API (Yelp's) that runs a search based on a "term" and a "location." I want to substitute a list of locations from another script I wrote into the first. I have been able to figure out how to import files and run them using `if __name__ == '__main__':` However, I realized that I'm not really trying to use the functions in another file... I'm trying to just substitute the location. How do I do that?

Here is what I have so far. This is the snippet of code I have for the function in python file "A" :

```
DEFAULT_TERM = ''
DEFAULT_LOCATION = 'San Francisco, CA'
DEFAULT_OFFSET = 0
DEFAULT_SORT = 2
```

(lots of code here)

```
def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

    parser.add_argument('-q', '--term', dest='term', default=DEFAULT_TERM,
                        type=str, help='Search term (default: %(default)s)')
    parser.add_argument('-l', '--location', dest='location',
                        default=DEFAULT_LOCATION, type=str,
                        help='Search location (default: %(default)s)')

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

---

and then in my other file (B):

```
locations = ['SF', 'NY', 'etc']
import sample

    sample.main()
```

---

I'm stuck! Calling `sample.main()` in file B doesn't substitute the locations into the "DEFAULT LOCATIONS" in file A. (I realize theres another way of making the "locations" as part of the `add_argument` for location, but I think that making them just substitute into DEFAULT LOCATIONS would be easier.) How do I make this work?

Answer (score 0):

Normally, your `main()` function calls `search(term, locaction)` after it has parsed the command line arguments to do the actual job. If it doesn't then modify it to do so. Then, in your another script, `import yelp` and call `yelp.search()` function (I've renamed `sample` to `yelp` for clarity):

```
import yelp

result = yelp.search(term, locations)
```

If you can't modify `sample.py` file then you could set `sys.argv` to emulate the desired command line:

```
import sys
import sample

sys.argv[1:] = ['-q', term, '-l', location]
sample.main()
```